# Ubuntu 16.10 makes every USB device write protected after i plug it in

Tags: usb, read-only, storage

Whenever I plug in any USB storage device, it automatically makes it write protected, it's happening for each and every USB device.

Any idea why and what's the solution for this?

Comment: Check your rules for user devices in `/etc/udev/rules.d` did you add any recently?

Comment: I didn't add any but In etc/udev/rules.d I found this file 70-snap.core.rules